# Electric potential in the center of a sphere inside uniformly charged insulator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, dielectric

> Given an insulator of some shape, which is uniformly charged $\rho_0$, we create a spherical cavity inside it, of radius $R$. (meaning we extract all the charges inside the cavity, but the remaining charges stays in place)
>
> Before creating the cavity, the electric potential at the center of the sphere, $O$, is $\varphi _0$.
>
> What is the electric potential in $O$, after the creation of the cavity?

(I assume the point of reference is at $\infty$ and the potential there is $0$)

I thought about looking at this as the sphere is uniformly charged with $-\rho_0$ and then the potential in $O$ is $\varphi _0 - \frac{k}{r} \rho_0 \frac{4 \pi R^2}{3}$, but it seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I don't know enough about that expression, so I can't judge it. But since potential is additive, we can say the final potential is the original potential minus the potential contributed by the sphere. Is that what you did?

Comment: @Digiproc yes, this is $\frac{kq}{r}$ where $q= \rho * Volume$

Comment: What is $r$ in your answer?

Comment: See : http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY204/tsl94.pdf

Comment: Do you get the right answer now? If you wish, you could post your calculation as an answer.

Comment: @sammygerbil I just calculated the potential wrong, it should be like the one in the last line in the link you provided, with $r=0$.

Comment: Please can you post your calculation, Dan.  Either in the question or as an answer. Then we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: I didn't consider the potential from $R$ to $\infty$, as seen in my try in my question. It should be exactly as the last line in your link with $r=0$.